# Communication between class data members in C++

Tags: c++, oop, segmentation-fault

Looking for how to best access class B's queue through A but I am receiving a segmentation fault. Also I am looking for the best way to communicate between these two classes. Are accessor methods ok in this scenario? What design pattern could work? Thanks

```
class B {
public:
    int get_int() { return qi.front(); }
    void put_int(int i) { qi.push(i); }
private:
    queue<int> qi;
};

class A 
{
public:
    void get_event() { cout << b->get_int() << endl; }
    void put_event(int a) { b->put_int(a); }
private:
    B *b;       
};


int main() {
    A a;
    a.put_event(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A::b` is an uninitialized pointer containing random garbage. Your program exhibits undefined behavior. It never actually creates an instance of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment problem is undefined initialization

you can fix that by using constructor for initialization

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
class B {
public:
    int get_int() { return qi.front(); }
    void put_int(int i)
    {
        qi.push(i);

    }

private:
    queue<int> qi;
};

class A
{
public:
    void get_event() { cout << b->get_int() << endl; }
    void put_event(int a) { b->put_int(a); }
    A()
    {
       b = new B();
    }
    ~A() { delete b; }
private:
    B *b;
};


int main() {
    A a;
    a.put_event(1);
    a.get_event();
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A a;
```

is an undefined reference, you have to initialize it with a costructor and since you didn't defined any, you must use the default one

```
A a=new A();
```

or better, write the costructors of the two classes as you prefer and use them.